# Using sqlalchemy together with cherrypy - how to guarantee parallel processing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

how I can use cherrypy together with sqlalchemy. And how I can guarantee the thread-safety of the cherrypy engine?

Comment: Hi @Markus, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some ["research effort"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CherryPy SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/ionrock/cherrypy-sqlalchemy)  [PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/CherryPy-SQLAlchemy/) it uses a CherryPy plugin and tool, that wraps over the SQLAlchemy sessions. The *thread safety* comes by the fact it wrap over the SQLAlchemy [scoped_session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html).